# Jersey MOXy not parsing snake_case

Tags: java, json, jersey, moxy

I'm passing a JSON object from a PUT request to my server. The request itself works, however the fields in the JSON which have an underscore (snake_case) seem to bi ignored. The request outputs the received data to see what comes out, and the value with the underscore converts to camelCase, and doesn't get parsed. Here's the class:

```
Public User{

private int id;
private String name;
private int some_value;

}
```

The JSON object I pass to the PUT request:

```
{ "id":1, "name":John, "some_value":5 }
```

The PUT method only returns what MOXy caught in this case

```
@PUT
@Path("user")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User addUser(User user){
    return user;
}
```

And the output is:

```
{ "id":1, "name":John, "someValue":0 }
```

Notice how "some_value" changed to "someValue" and didn't get the actual value updated. Any idea on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MOXy follows Java Bean conventions by default, which suggest camel case. If you don't want to (or can't) use camel case, you can add an annotation to the field:

```
@XmlElement(name = "some_value")
private int some_value;
```

If you don't want to annotate all your fields, use an [XMLNameTransformer](https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/moxy/advanced_concepts002.htm).

Comment: That took care of half of the problem, the value is now updated. But the output still shows camelCase. Any idea on how to fix that? Or do I just have to go with that?

Comment: The `@XmlElement` annotation should apply to both reading and writing, so I'm guessing the problem must be somewhere else. You could try posting a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you need more help.

Comment: Actually this doesn't work. It adds another field "some_value" to the existing JSON, now it has both that and "someValue", but with the passed value

Comment: As a wild guess, do you have any getters/setters on your `User` class? Because you'll need to annotate or change those as well (or tell MOXy to only use one or the other).

Comment: I do actually, the setters/getters are passed a variable of the same name and then the value is updated to the passed value, i.e. this.some_value = some_value. Does this mean I need to put the annotation in the getter/setter argument fields as well?

Comment: No, you put them above the getter/setter, or [tell JAXB to ignore getters and setters entirely](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html).